# Google analytics for Google apps-script doesn't show any data after a few weeks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have an apps-script that I want to impression count in Google-Analytics.

I have created a new GA account + data stream.

Copied it's `measurement id` and put it in my app-script code:

```
/**
 * Function to track all (internal/external) usage
 * @param {string} page tracked
 */
function sendGA(page) {
  var cid = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(Utilities.computeDigest(
      Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256,
      ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()));
  try {
    var data = {
      'v': '1',
      'tid': 'G-9S9...',
      'z': Math.floor(Math.random()*10E7),
      't':'pageview',
      'dl': SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl() + '/' + page,
      'cid': cid
    };
    var payload = Object.keys(data).map(
      function(key) {
        return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
      }
    ).join('&');
    var options = {
      'method' : 'POST',
      'payload' : payload
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect', options);
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

[image]

and

[image]

These were my installation steps, have I missed anything?

The `measurement id` goes in here? `'tid': 'G-9S9...',`

Comment: You may want to check this article at support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153#add-tag "Set up data collection (for websites)." I'm not an expert on Google Analytics but as per their official documentation, the website should be owned by you & you/your developer need to access its html source code. This is because you'll need to add the "Analytics tag" to your web pages to begin seeing data in your Google Analytics 4 property.

Comment: Right, but that's an app-script behind a spreadsheet so there is no "client side editable html"